# Do iCloud email addresses ignore periods like Gmail?

Tags: icloud, email

In a Gmail email, you can put periods in your email, but in the end, the address is seen without them.
So dave.tess@gmail.com is also seen as davetess@gmail.com or even d.a.v.e.tess@gmail.com.

My question is, does iCloud handle emails this way too? If I have an address with periods in it, could I send an email to the same address without periods and receive it?

Comment: superset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865869/do-all-email-providers-ignore-periods-in-front-of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this doesn't work for iCloud email addresses. Just tried it and the email failed to deliver — the email must be exactly correct.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, I didn't get a permanent failure message from the mail daemon for my no dot test even though it never arrives:
myname@icloud.com (never arrives), m.y.n.a.m.e@icloud.com (failure notification), my.name@icloud.com (valid, arrives).

Answer (score 2):

You can create an email alias in iCloud to accept your dotted version.

Eg. 
If your iCloud address is mydoghasfleas@icloud.com, then my.dog.has.fleas@icloud.com won't work, unless you add an email alias for it in your iCloud email account. See:

http://help.apple.com/icloud/#mm6b1a490a

For full instructions on how to create your email aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this depends.

If the address was set up under the me.com days and you already created an alias with the dot then it will work. Otherwise, it will not.

I have an address previously set up with an alias (during iCloud's me.com days) and mail will be received at the "dotted" address. I think currently iCloud does not allow additional aliases if you were not grandfathered under me.com.